# Given one data point, why is the population standard deviation equal to zero but the sample standard deviation is undefined?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

How come if we're given only one data point the sample standard deviation would be undefined because of n - 1?

Comment: To understand, you need to understand the difference between population standard deviation and sample standard deviation.  When referring to sample standard deviation, we are trying to use the available data to describe the trends that we expect to experience for a larger set than what we got actual data for.  As such, we try to inflate the numbers ever so slightly and we accomplish this by using a division of $n-1$ rather than a division by $n$ in the formula.  With only one data point however, this would be a division by $0$ which is of course undefined.  You cannot divide by zero here.

Comment: I think you mean the $\textrm{unbiased estimator}$ for the variance of the population. And yes it is undefined for $n=1$. Without variance in the sample you cannot estimate the variance of the population.

Answer (score 0):

Uncorrected (biased) sample variance is defined (and is $0$). Corrected (unbiased) sample variance is not defined.

It's because there is **no** unbiased estimator that takes only one sample. Indeed, would there be, it should be zero everywhere (as for random variable that is always $x$ it should give $0$), but zero isn't unbiased estimator of variance (it's expectation wrt any random variable is $0$, but there are variables with non-zero variance).